# Climbing long beans leaves started have white spots

Tags: beans

6 months ago, I planted the climbing beans in a container. They started growing beans since last month. We had like 2 harvest of maybe 40-50 beans. It is still growing beans but but now the leaves started having some white spots, doesn't look right. On google search, seems to be some fungus infection. Or is it the random weather condition. Any idea, how to cure it? .

Location: Melbourne, Australia.[image]

Comment: A photo of the underside of leaves may help. It seems like very small aphids or white flies, possibly red spider-mite (though mites, not true spiders). Do you have white flies flying around each time you shake the leaves? or thrips? http://www.omafra.gov.on.ca/english/crops/facts/14-001.htm

Answer (score 1):

They do look like marks left by aphids.

Spraying **mineral** or **neem** oil works for my wife's garden.

- There are some solutions at [wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Control-Aphids).

  1. Spray the plants with a strong stream of water
  2. Remove the aphids using your hands
  3. Dust the plants with flour to help deal with an aphid invasion
  4. Wipe the plants down with a mild soap and water
  5. Enlist Predators and Traps
  6. Draw in bug-eating birds to help fix the problem
  7. Stop ants from helping out aphids
  8. Mix together essential oils to use on the plants
  9. Create a homemade garlic spray to use on the aphids
  10. Spray neem oil onto plants affected by aphids
  11. Use an insecticidal soap to help control aphids
- If you want a  commercial solution, [Yates have some]
  (https://www.yates.co.nz/problem-solver/pests/aphids/)

  1. Bug Oil Insect Spray
  2. Natures Way Organic Citrus, Vegie and Ornamental Spray
  3. Conquer Oil
  4. Mavrik Insect and Mite Spray

Answer (score 0):

Sucking creatures. Each dot is one wound. That is mites or aphids etc. I garden in Melbourne. At this stage not a problem, and with not much solution.